# Binding to a static property is not responding to PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am fairly new to XAML and WPF and have read numerous examples of how bind control properties but none seem to apply to my problem.

I have a static class Analyse that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged

Summary of the code below

```
class Analyse : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static DataSet moodleData;  // Dataset containing the log data for analysis
    private static bool dataPresent = true;

    public static Boolean DataPresent
    {
        get { return dataPresent; }
        set
        {
            if (dataPresent != value)
            {
                dataPresent = value;
                NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("DataPresent");
            }
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged
     = delegate { };

    private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    #endregion

    public static void clearData()
    {
        try
        {
            moodleData.Clear();
            DataPresent = false;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

My XAML includes the name space local

```
<Window x:Name="TheMainWindow" x:Class="MoodleLogAnalyse.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MoodleLogAnalyse"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="556.88" Width="793" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
```

And the button is bound correctly

```
<Button Name="OpenButton" Command="Open" 
       IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Analyse.DataPresent},
       Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
       Content="Open Grades" />
```

The property is definitely bound to the IsEnabled, changing the dataPresent definition manually in code enables and disables the button but a dynamic change such as switching between true and false such as calling the clear data method does not change the IsEnabled state of the button at run time.

The property change event is triggering as I have inserted break point to check.

I cannot see where I am going wrong with this!  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting comment but doesn't help resolve the problem!

Comment: Actually, since WPF 4.5, it should work with the StaticPropertyChanged event. However, your binding should be `{Binding Path=(local:Analyse.DataPresent), ...}`.

Comment: It also seems that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged isn't necessary. You might instead declare your class static: `static class Analyse { ... }`.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the help this has sorted it.  Could you explain the difference between the two, {Binding Path=(local:Analyse.DataPresent) and {Binding Source={x:Static local:Analyse.DataPresent} for others who would read this post.

Comment: @Clemens You are right it doesn't need the inheritance, seems a bit bizarre but that might just be me needing to read a bit more understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Source` property is used to store the object which will be used as the alternative binding source (by default, bindings use `DataContext`).

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Analyze.DataPresent}}" />
```

So when you use the code above then the `Static` extension provides the current value of the `DataPresent` property and that value is stored in the `Source` property. In this case the binding uses a boxed constant value (`true` or `false`) as the source.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Path=(local:Analyze.DataPresent)}" />
```

But when you specify the `Path` property, the binding locates your static class and binds to the property. In this case the static `DataPresent` property is the source and the `StaticPropertyChanged` event is used to notify the binding about updates.

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` cannot be used in the case of binding to a static property because there is no instance is used to access that property. The corresponding static event must be used instead.

The name of the event must be equal to `StaticPropertyChanged` and its type must be `EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs>`. Or the name must consist of two parts: the property name and suffix `Changed`. In the last case the event's type must be `EventHandler` because the event notifies only about changes of the corresponding property.

This means that:

1. The class `Analyze` can be static because `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't necessary.
2. The event `StaticPropertyChanged` can be renamed to `DataPresentChanged` and its type can be changed to `EventHandler`.

In other words:

```
public static class Analyze
{
    public static DataSet moodleData;  // Dataset containing the log data for analysis
    private static bool dataPresent = true;

    public static Boolean DataPresent
    {
        get { return dataPresent; }
        set
        {
            if (dataPresent != value)
            {
                dataPresent = value;
                DataPresentChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler DataPresentChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Useful links:

1. [Binding.Source Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Binding to static properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties)

Comment: @Stephen Smith - You should mark this as the answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments and responses they were both very helpful and insightful,  hopefully they will help others and not just me!

Comment: Folks, this is the syntax you are looking for.